# How to search for words with Sublime Text Package Control

Tags: controls, package, sublimetext3

I installed Package Control for Sublime Text 3. Now I'm trying to install various other plugins but find the search function hard to handle because of a strange behaviour:

Instead of finding items that contain the word I enter, it finds items that contain the letters I enter in the order that I enter them. Like that, I get way too many hits, most of them irrelevant.
Is there a setting to fix this, or to search for words instead of letters?

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's how the command palette search works. As far as I know, there's no way to make it look for exact matches. The best advice I could offer is to continue typing the package name. Alternatively, if you know the names of all the packages you want, you can simply modify the `Package Control.sublime-settings` file in your `User` folder. Then restart the editor. I believe it will grab all of the packages that you want.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The problem is that I don't know the names of the packages. What I'm looking for is plugins for Sublime Linter, so I search for "lint" - lots of results for entries that contain these letters. I really don't understand why the devs chose this unusual way of searching. I have never seen such behaviour anywhere else.

Comment: It's a fuzzy search algorithm. For somethings it works well (say the command palette). For example, if I want to change the syntax of a file to python I simply type `ss py`. It's clear where that is nicer than typing out `set syntax python`. Of course, others, such as package control, it doesn't work as well. Have you considered searching wbond's site for the packages (so you can get the names). It might work better. https://sublime.wbond.net/